# how to get multiple attribute values in one array

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I have problem in to get the attribute values in xml response dis my

Xml

```
<History>
<master ids=\"1\" >
    <historypoints id=\"1\" bankerpoint=\"9\" playerpoint=\"0\" win=\"1\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
</master>
<master ids=\"2\" >
    <historypoints id=\"2\" bankerpoint=\"5\" playerpoint=\"7\" win=\"0\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
    <historypoints id=\"3\" bankerpoint=\"6\" playerpoint=\"7\" win=\"0\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
    <historypoints id=\"4\" bankerpoint=\"0\" playerpoint=\"4\" win=\"0\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
</master>
<master ids=\"3\" >
    <historypoints id=\"5\" bankerpoint=\"5\" playerpoint=\"3\" win=\"1\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
    <historypoints id=\"6\" bankerpoint=\"6\" playerpoint=\"0\" win=\"1\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
    <historypoints id=\"7\" bankerpoint=\"9\" playerpoint=\"0\" win=\"1\" playerpair=\"1\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
    <historypoints id=\"8\" bankerpoint=\"6\" playerpoint=\"0\" win=\"1\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
</master>
<master ids=\"4\" >
    <historypoints id=\"9\" bankerpoint=\"0\" playerpoint=\"8\" win=\"0\" playerpair=\"0\" bankerpair=\"0\" />
</master>
```

In dis above xml i need to get "win" attribute values in one array,anyone could u please help me out dis problem thanks.

dis my code

```
   NSString *label;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    NSLog(@"elementName %@",elementName);
     NSLog(@"attributeDict %@",attributeDict);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"History"]) {
        label = @"History";

    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"historypoints"]) {
        label = @"historypoints";

        if ([attributeDict valueForKey:@"win"]) {
            NSLog(@"Log values is more useful ");
            label = @"win";
        }
    }
}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"foundCharacters %@",string);

    if ([label isEqualToString:@"win"]){

        self.typeStr = string;
        [typearr addObject:string];

    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    NSLog(@"didEndElement elementName:%@",elementName);
}
```

Comment: @Wain i have posted my code now could u check that please ,i have tried like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath here. Here is the expression to solve you task.

```
/History/master/historypoints/@win
```

I don't know much about ios platform, so you need to find some xml library that supports xpath on ios.
And here's an [online xpath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/) to play with xpath expressions.

Also note that your xml is missing the closing "History" root tag.

Comment: i have used like dis to get attribue see my code i have posted now.

Comment: i have tried that path based i cant get any values from xml in that array it will show null.it wont go found character method.